# Add source object into destination list

Tags: c#, automapper

Here is my source class:

```
class source
{
   int Prop1 {get; set;}
   string Prop2 {get; set;}
}
```

Here is destination:

```
class dest
{
   int Prop1 {get; set;}
   List<string> Prop2 {get; set;}
}
```

I want to create a map that would:

1. Insert source.prop2 into dest.prop2
2. If dest.prop2 is null create and add

No such example found on [documentation here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so scenario was not that simple,
**community let me know if I shall update my question, I will**

source class:

```
class TSource
{
   int Prop1 {get; set;}
   TSomeModelDto Prop2 {get; set;}
}
```

destination:

```
class TDestination
{
   int Prop1 {get; set;}
   List<TSomeModel> Prop2 {get; set;}
}
```

where TSomeModelDto is Dto for TSomeModel

**Soltion**

```
CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>()
  .ForMember(dst => dst.Prop1, src => src.MapFrom(p => p.Prop1))
  .AfterMap((s, d) => 
   { 
        if (d.Prop2 == null) d.Prop2 = new AutoConstructedList<TSomeModel>();

        d.Prop2 .Add(new TSomeModelDto 
        {
           PropX = s.TSomeModelDto.PropX
        });
   }
```

Comment: the inner logic is the important part of the answer. without it the answer is worthless. If you edit your answer and add working solution I will change my vote

Comment: @Simonare here it goes, hope it makes sense now

Comment: @Simonare i was expecting you to remove the vote down , as the changes you sought I've done.